# Writing Excel add-on statement to hash function?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, syntax

So I have a BASE64SHA1 statement write now that assigns an ID to every unique first + last name combination in my spreadsheet.

The statement is as follows:

> =BASE64SHA1(C2)&BASE64SHA1(D2)

(The first and last name in separate columns)

The only issue with this is that there are tons of blank cells in the name columns that all have been assigned the same unique code.

What I'm trying to do is execute the original hash function above, and if either name column (first or last name) is blank, then assign the unique value based on the email column *ONLY* if the email is unique.

So something like this

> =BASE64SHA1(C2)&BASE64SHA1(D2)

followed by

- IF first &/or last name = "", then assign the unique value based on email column ONLY IF email is unique.

Hopefully that makes sense, any help about how I would write that statement would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Play with this for a start. I will try revisit later.   `=IF(OR(ISBLANK(C2),ISBLANK(D2)),IF(COUNTIF($E$2:$E$1000,E2)=1,"PUT YOUR EMAIL HASH FORMULA HERE","EMAIL NOT UNIQUE"),BASE64SHA1(C2)&BASE64SHA1(D2))`   Names in cols C&D, Emails in Col E

Comment: Hi Stax, first part of the statement looks great. [=IF(OR(ISBLANK(C2),ISBLANK(D2)),IF(COUNTIF($E$2:$E$1000,E2)=1,]

for the EMAIL NOT UNIQUE quote, shouldn't the hash function be able to identify which code was originally assigned to the email? Given that it's not unique and was already assigned a code. 

Also the email hash function would just be "BASE64SHA1(email column) correct?

Comment: Why not just apply filter for unique email.. then only apply the sha1 formula?

Comment: Yup, I figured that out shortly after posting the comment. Thanks